# Azure VM - Can't connect to a TCP server that listens on a specific port

Tags: sockets, azure, networking, tcp, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to establish a TCP connection between an on-prem client and an Azure VM (Standard D1 v2) running Windows 2K16.

On the VM I'm running a simple TCP server (see code below) that receives the port.  I've passes port 51515 in the arguments.

The network interface have a public IP I'm trying to use.

I've added an inbound port rule on TCP port 51515 on the portal (source=any, source port=*, destination=any, dest. port=51515, protocol=TCP, action=allow).

Windows Firewall on the VM is off (public, domain and private).

I'm using Telnet from the on-prem side, using the public IP and the 51515 port.  Getting the could not open connection message there.

I've tried accessing the IIS on the VM and it is accessible from the on prem using another inbound rule.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Tom

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var server = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, int.Parse(args[0])));
            server.AllowNatTraversal(true);
            server.Start();
            server.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ContinueWith(c => System.Console.WriteLine("Client connected from:" + c.Result.Client.RemoteEndPoint));
            System.Console.WriteLine("server listens... press any key to exit");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e);
            System.Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, does it work now?

Comment: Yes, it is!  Thanks EJP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EJP said, `IPAddress.Loopback` means `127.0.0.1`, the service only could access inside VM.

You need bind port on `0.0.0.0` or VM's private ip. Like below:

```
var server = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(args[0])));
```

Comment: @Atom If you modify bind IP, could you access the port?

Comment: @Atom You could use `netstat -ant|findstr <port>` to check, if your code like mine, the port is listening on `0.0.0.0`. I test in my lab, I could access it from my local PC.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only listening on a specific port but also at a specific address. You don't want that. You are binding the server socket to `IPAddress.Loopback`, i.e. 127.0.0.1, which means it won't accept any connections from outside its local host.

Bind it to 0.0.0.0.